# Node - associate tables with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to associate tables in such a way that:

- A group has many documents
- A document belongs to a group
- A group belongs to an user
- An user has many groups

When i try to list all from table 'Group' including 'User', throws an error saying that User is not associated to Group.

**My models:**

> Document.js

```
const Document = conn.define('document', {
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    footer: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    }

})

Document.sync()
Document.associate = (models) => {
    Document.belongsTo(models.Group, {foreignKey: 'groupId', as: 'Group'})
}

module.exports = Document
```

> Group.js

```
const Group = conn.define('group', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
})

Group.sync()
Group.associate = (models) => {
    Group.hasMany(models.Document, {foreignKey: 'groupId', as: 'Document'})
    Group.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'User'})
}

module.exports = Group
```

> User.js

```
const User = conn.define('user', {
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
})

User.sync()
User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(models.Group, {foreignKey: 'groupId', as: 'Group'})
}

module.exports = User
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see one mistake in your code. You should use the same foreign key name for one to many relationships. Otherwise, you will have two different columns in your database.

Here you should use `userId` as a foreign key. Sequelize creates the id column in the `belongsTo` model. So there will be a `userId` in the `Group` model if you use it like this:

```js
User.hasMany(Group, {foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'Group'});
Group.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'User'});
```

Also, **try not to create associations in model files**. Consider using index.js files and you can create all of your associations in there.

```
src
    app.js
    models
        index.js
        user.js
        group.js
        document.js
```

Keep your model definition in their files. Export the created model classes. Include them in your `index.js` file. Create necessary associations and export them again.

src/models/index.js

```js
const User = require('./user');
const Group = require('./group');
const Document = require('./document');

User.hasMany(Group, {foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'Group'});
Group.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'User'});

// Define what associations you need.

module.exports = {
    User,
    Group,
    Document
};
```

Comment: @Mansur Why do you think it's preferable to create the associations in the index file instead of in the model classes?

Comment: @Erma There are lots of reasons. It would keep all relations in a single file so you can take a look at one file to see what is associated with what. It's of course preference but I think it makes it clear. It's also the recommended way of sequelize package itself.

Comment: @Mansur since you mentioned "It's also the recommended way of sequelize package itself.", do you have any reference I can read about this? Thanks

Comment: This is an old answer. I don't really remember. As far as I remember, it was how `sequelize-cli` creates for you.