# Sequelize: throw new Error(`${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my program:

movie.js

```js
import  { DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
import Actor from './actor'
import ActorMovies from './actormovies'
import { sequelize } from '../../db/seq'

const Movie = sequelize.define('Movie', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
Movie.belongsToMany(Actor, { through: ActorMovies });

export default Movie
```

actor.js

```js
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
import Movie from './movie'
import ActorMovies from './actormovies'
import { sequelize } from '../../db/seq'

const Actor = sequelize.define('Actor', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
Actor.belongsToMany(Movie, { through: ActorMovies });

export default Actor
```

actormovies.js

```js
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
import Movie from './movie'
import Actor from './actor'
import { sequelize } from '../../db/seq'

const ActorMovies = sequelize.define('ActorMovies', {
    MovieId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: Movie, 
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    ActorId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: Actor, 
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
});

export default ActorMovies
```

It will threw an error

```sh
throw new Error(`${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

I guess it may be use diffierent sequelize in movie.js and actor.js, but I am not sure.

Does someone have already see an error that look like that ? I search for few days without any suitable issue, if someone could help I'll really appreciate,

thank !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are trying to use .belongsToMany in their own files.

Simple explanation: When you require one of the model files, one of them is not defined as a sequelize model yet.

Try to use index.js file for your model folder. [Take a look at my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363328/node-associate-tables-with-sequelize/62366106#62366106)

You can read @Dorian Jakov Stern Vukotic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070808/hasmany-called-with-something-thats-not-an-instance-of-sequelize-model).