# How to correctly initiate n:m associations in Sequelize

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

In my express app, I have two models which I want to associate with each other through an n:m-association: `User`, `Game`. This should pass via the joint model `GamePlayer`. I read in the [Sequelize Docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships) that I have to call `.belongsToMany()` on both `User` and `Game`. However, as soon as I do this, my app crashes with the error `GameScore.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model`. As shown, there is also a `GameScore` model, which belongs to `Game` and `Game` always has one `GameScore`. I tried setting a `references` object in the `GameScore` model, I tried using `.hasMany()` in `GamePlayer` along with `.belongsTo(GamePlayer)` in both `User` and `Game`, all to no avail. As soon as I remove the association, the app doesn't crash anymore. I don't know, if I'm misunderstanding something here, or if I'm just being blind/missing the forest for the trees. Any help would me much appreciated!

I'm using version `6.3.3` of Sequelize.

Find below the relevant code of all the involved models (imports and interface declarations omitted):

**User Model**

```
export default class User extends Model { /* ... just variable declarations */ }

User.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    deleted: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
}, {
    tableName: 'users',
    sequelize: db,
    underscored: true,
});

User.belongsToMany(Game, {
    through: GamePlayer,
});
```

**Game Model**

```
export default class Game extends Model { /* ... just variable declarations */ }

Game.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    deleted: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
}, {
    tableName: 'games',
    sequelize: db,
    underscored: true,
});

Game.hasOne(GameScore);

Game.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: GamePlayer,
});
```

**GamePlayer Model**

```
export default class GamePlayer extends Model { /* ... just variable declarations */ }

GamePlayer.init({
    gameId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        references: {
            model: Game,
            key: 'id',
        }
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        references: {
            model: User,
            key: 'id',
        }
    },
    team: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT({ 
            length: 1, 
            unsigned: true,
        }),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    win: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
    },
}, {
    tableName: 'game_players',
    sequelize: db,
    underscored: true,
});
```

**GameScore Model**

```
export default class GameScore extends Model { /* ... just variable declarations */ }

GameScore.init({
    gameId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    scoreTeam1: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT({
            length: 1,
            unsigned: true,
        }),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    scoreTeam2: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT({
            length: 1,
            unsigned: true,
        }),
        allowNull: false,
    },
}, {
    tableName: 'game_scores',
    sequelize: db,
    underscored: true,
});

GameScore.belongsTo(Game, {
    foreignKey: 'gameId',
});
```

Comment: Yup, it does, thank you! I'm going to add an answer with this link

Answer (score 0):

The comment of Mansur pointed me in the right direction. Go give his answer an upvote here: [Sequelize: throw new Error(`${this.name}.belongsToMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897998/sequelize-throw-new-errorthis-name-belongstomany-called-with-something-tha)