# NodeJs Sequelize Relations/Associations connect model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, relationship, model-associations

I'm facing issues with Sequelize Relationship hasMany and belongsToMany. I have added a screenshot of database relationships.
[image]

User Model - Users.js

```
const connection = require('../db/connection'); 
const MessageDetails = require('./Message');
const User = connection.sequelize.define('users',{
    id: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },   
    full_name: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    created_at: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.DATE
    }    
},{
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at'    
});
User.hasMany(MessageDetails,{
    foreignKey: 'user_id',
    sourceKey: 'id',
    as: 'message'
})
module.exports = User;
```

Message Module - Messages.js

```
const connection = require('../db/connection'); 
const User = require('./User')

const Message = connection.sequelize.define('messages',{
    id: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },   
    send_to: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    send_by: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    message: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    created_at: {
        type: connection.Sequelize.DATE
    }    
},{
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at'
});
Message.belongsToMany(User , {
    foreignKey: 'id',
    sourceKey: 'send_to',
    as: 'user_send_to'
})
Message.belongsToMany(User , {
    foreignKey: 'id',
    sourceKey: 'send_by',
    as: 'user_send_by'
})
module.exports = Message;
```

> ERROR -  SequelizeEagerLoadingError: users is not associated to
> messages!

Also, I try with `through`

```
User.belongsToMany(Message, { as: 'Users', through: 'user_send_by', foreignKey: 'id' })
```

But getting same error.

Query -

```
MessageSchema.findAll({
  attributes: ['message', 'id','send_by','send_to'],
  include:[
      {
          attributes: ['full_name'],
          model: UserSchema,
          as: 'users',
      }
  ],
  where:{
      $or: {
          send_by: 1,
          send_to: 1
      }
  },
}).
```

sequelize version - "^5.21.2"

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363328/node-associate-tables-with-sequelize/62366106#62366106