# Sequelize not recognizing associations

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a proyect using MySql db and sequelize via Express, and I am getting an error which I understand what it means but I don't know why its happening.

So the error consists in that Sequelize doesn't recognize my associations even though I associated them. The association is between products and category.

This is my products model with the association on the bottom:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes){
    let alias = "Product";

    let cols = {
        id: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING
        },
        description: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING
        },
        size: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING
        },
        price: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        img_url: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING
        },
        category_id: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
        }
    };

    let config = {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: "product"
    };

    let Product = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

    Product.associate = function(models) {
        Product.belongsTo(models.Category, {
            as: "categorias",
            foreignKey: "category_id"
        })
    }
    

    return Product;
}
```

This is my Categorys model with the associartion on the bottom:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, dataTypes) {
    let alias = "Category";

    let cols = {
        id: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING
        },
        genre: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING
        }
    };

    let config = {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: "category"
    };
    
    let Category = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);
    
    Category.associate = function(models) {
        Category.hasMany(models.Product, {
            as: "productos",
            foreignKey: "category_id"
        });
    };

    return Category;
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Association with alias "categorias" does not exist on Product
    at Function._transformStringAssociation (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:332:15)
    at Function._conformInclude (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:363:38)
    at /Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:326:59
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function._conformIncludes (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:326:39)
    at Function._baseMerge (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:793:10)
    at Function._defaultsOptions (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:830:17)
    at Function._injectScope (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:3292:10)
    at /Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1709:12
    at tryCatcher (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
    at Function.findAll (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1708:23)
    at list (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/controllers/apiControllers/productosController.js:5:24)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/kingbc/Desktop/Nordelta-Team-1/OurWeb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

Comment: show a code where you register associations

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363328/node-associate-tables-with-sequelize/62366106#62366106

Comment: Can't reproduce it for `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`. It works fine.